# Sending ssh command from windows jenkins slave to raspberry pi

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, ssh, raspberry-pi

In python these are the commands I am sending:

```
os.system("ssh -i %s %s -t 'gpio mode 0 out'" % (id_rsa_path, self.hostname))
os.system("ssh -i %s %s -t 'gpio write %s %s'" %(id_rsa_path, self.hostname, pin, value))
```

Both of which when I run my script locally on this jenkins slave work with no issues. My jenkins slave opens a python virutal env and executes a py.test test that executes these commands as the setup.

When i run from jenkins I get this output `'Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.'`

I have tried multiple different things I tried `-T`, I tried `-tt` , `-t -t`. I tried on full call with `gpio mode 0 out; gpio write %s%s; exit`.

I have tried several things, is there anyone that would know why I cannot get this to run in jenkins successful and trigger this command to set the gpio of my raspberry pi. Would greatly appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Aside from the pseudo-terminal message, what actual problem are you having? Do you just want to get rid of the pseudo-terminal message? Or do you need ssh to allocate a pseudo-tty on the remote system?

Comment: The problem I am having is that the command is not being executed on the pi at all from the windows machine.